# How can I pick a "best match" in Apache Spark when aggregating within a DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have this data in a Spark data frame:

```
Person   Position
-----------------
Tom      Gold
Tom      Silver
Tom      Silver
Dick     Silver
Dick     Silver
Dick     null
Harry    Gold
Harry    Silver
Alice    Bronze
Alice    null
Bob      null
Bob      null
```

This is what I want to achieve in my output:

```
Person   BestPosition
-----------------
Tom      Gold
Dick     Silver
Harry    Gold
Alice    Bronze
Bob      null
```

This is not the real scenario but it's a pretty good approximation. The ranking order of positions can either be hard-coded or config driven, I don't mind (there are only 3 or 4 in the real scenario and they won't change).

If I were doing this in C# I think it would look something like this:

```
var data = new List<int>{}.Select(x => new { Name = "Tom",  Position = "Gold" },  ... etc);
var aggregation = data
    .GroupBy(scores => scores.Name)
    .Select(grouping => new {
        Name = grouping.Key,
        BestPosition = new [] {"Gold", "Silver", "Bronze"}.FirstOrDefault(x => grouping.Any(score => score.Position == x))
    })
    .ToList();
```

I'm writing my application in Spark for .NET (which in retrospect was a bad decision I can't afford to change direction now). I appreciate nobody else is using Spark for .NET, but what I'm struggling with here is more concept than code so if anyone can solve the problem in Scala/Java/Python I'm pretty sure I can convert.

I'm pretty new to Spark so the solution might be obvious, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution using `collect_set` and `array_contains` with groupBy:

```
df.groupBy($"Person").agg(collect_set(col("Position")).alias("Position")) 
  .withColumn("Position", when(array_contains($"Position", "Gold"), "Gold") 
                          .when(array_contains($"Position", "Silver"), "Silver") 
                          .when(array_contains($"Position", "Bronze"), "Bronze")
             ) 
  .show()
```

Gives:

```
+------+--------+
|Person|Position|
+------+--------+
|   Tom|    Gold|
|  Dick|  Silver|
|   Bob|    null|
| Alice|  Bronze|
| Harry|    Gold|
+------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks, that works a treat - I 'm sure the other solution would have probably worked fine too (thanks Vamsi) but I went with this one as it was a closer fit to the code I already had in place, and felt slightly more readable to me.

Answer (score 1):

PySpark sql solution. The priority list can be set in the `order by` clause of a window function, which can then be used to pick the best row for a person.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number,when,col
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy(col('Person')).orderBy(when(col('Position') == 'Gold',1)
                                              .when(col('Position') == 'Silver',2)
                                              .when(col('Position') == 'Bronze',3)
                                              .otherwise(4)
                                             )
rnum_df = df.withColumn('rnum',row_number().over(w))
result = rnum_df.filter(col('rnum') == 1).select(df.columns)
result.show()
```